# Security (aka Permissions) and Lucene - How ? Should it be done?

Tags: security, lucene

First some background to my question.

- Individual entities can have read Permissions.
- If a user fails a *read* permission check they cant see that instance.

The probelm relates to introducing Lucene and performing a search which simply returns a list of matching entity instances. My code would then need to filter entities one by one. This approach is extremely inefficient as the situation exists that a user may only be able to see a small minority and checking many to return a few is less than ideal.

What approaches or how would developers solve this problem - keeping in mind that indexing and searches are performed using Lucene ?

**EDIT**

**Definitions**

- A User may belong to many Groups.
- A Role may have many Groups - these can change.
- A Permission has a Role - (indirection).
- X can have a read Permission.
- It is possible for the definition of a Role to change at any time.

**Indexing**

- Adding the set of Groups (expanding a Permmission) at index time may result in the definition becoming out of sync when the list of member groups for a Role change.
- I am hoping to avoid having to reindex X whenever the definition of a Permission/Role changes.

**Security Check**

- To pass a Permission check a User must belong to a group that is within the set of groups belong to the Role for a given Permission.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the number of different security groups that are relevant in your context and how the security applies to your indexed data.

We had a similar issue which we solved the following way: When indexing we added the allowed groups to the document and when searching we added a boolean query with the groups the user was a member of. That performed well in our scenario.

Comment: Probably we did something very similar: the indexed objects have groups id:s with read privileges in a metadata field: "G1, G6, G203," and searches are just targeted with "contains G1 or G70". Also extends to users by using a different prefix.

Comment: I use the same idea, here is my concrete implementation: http://lifeinide.blogspot.com/2013/02/lucene-permissions-and-hibernate-search.html

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your security model. If permissions are simple - say you have three classes of documents - It is probably best to build a separate Lucene index per class, and merge the results when a user can see more than one class.
[The Solr security Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity) suggests something similar to HakonB's suggestion - adding user's credentials to the query and searching by them.
See also [this discussion in the Lucene user group](http://www.lucidimagination.com/search/document/2c0aaac184910a7d/lucene_security_advice#efd417c4124aa5d1).
Another strategy will be to wrap the Lucene search with a separate security class that does additional filtering out of Lucene. It may be faster if you can do this using a database for the permissions.

Edit:
I see you have a rather complex permission system. Your basic design choice is whether to implement it inside Lucene or outside Lucene. My advice is to use Lucene as a search engine (its primary strength) and use another system/application for security. If you choose to use Lucene for security anyway, I suggest you learn [Lucene Filters](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/FilteringOptions) well, and use a bitset filter in order to filter a query's results. It does have the problems you listed of having to keep the permissions updated.

Comment: Added detail to my original answer. HTH

Answer (score 0):

As Yuval mentioned, it might be worth having the permission mechanism independent of the lucene index.

One way to do it is to implement your own [`Collector`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Collector.html), that will filter out the results that the user should not have access to.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is having two kind of documents:

1) Real_documents with a field called: "DocumentID"

2) A security document with fields: "Role" "Groups" "Users" "PermisionId" "DocumentsIds"

then a pseudo-code could be:

```
   Field[] docIds =searcher.search("Users", "currentUser").getFields("DocumentIds");
   TermsFilter filter = new TermFilter();

   foreach(field:docIDs){
       filter.add(new Term(field.field(),field.text());
   }
   searcher.search(query.getWeight(searcher), filter, numberOfDocuments);
```

Being that Lucene is very fast on searching two searches are really easy to make. In this way you also have a better tf-idf per user.