# Filter a Lucene query with complex access rights

Tags: c#, full-text-search, lucene.net, lucene

**The context :**

A Lucene.Net index indexing entities (simple, right ?)

**The needs :**

Return only the documents that the user querying has access to (still quite classic).

**The constraints :**

The rights are defined through a large set of ACL of several types.

The simple types are things like "User owns the entity" or "User created the entity". As the owner and creator ids are stored in each document, these ACL are easy enough to query.

But some ACL say "User is manager of the user owning the entity" for example. It's easy to get the list of users the current user is the manager of, but what I need is a way to filter a result against all these ids.

**What I tried :**

I built a custom filter that compares each relevant document field with each id provided, which works, but the complexity of this filter is O(n²), making it particularly inefficient when dealing with large query results sets against large list of users ids.

Including each authorized id with each document could also work (a variant of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823746/security-aka-permissions-and-lucene-how-should-it-be-done)), but the index size would exponentially increase, not mentioning that updating the index would become extremely painful (the ACL or relations between users can change anytime, of course, and it would become mandatory to compute access for each document each time a modification is done...)

I'm running out of ideas here, did anyone out there meet a problem like this ?

Any idea welcome.

Comment: Some time ago I have answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13869548/7345), maybe my answer will still be relevant for your case?

Comment: @mindas Thanks for this clear answer. It sums up almost everything I could think about. #1 is not applicable, for scale reasons. #2 : I tried to, but was not able to find a document grouping pattern. #3 : Given the poor results I get on a not so big index, I doubt the client will handle it better on real large ones. #4 and #5 are what I described in my attempts.